# Having Trouble installing dependencies for OpenCV on RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, opencv

for some reason, when i run the code below i get the following error. what should i do? I'm trying to install opencv for python 3.

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
```

> Err:1 http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian stretch/main armhf
>   libjbig-dev armhf 2.1-3.1   Could not connect to
>   raspbian-us.ngc292.space:80 (198.211.116.210). - connect (113: No
>   route to host) Err:3 http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian
>   stretch/main armhf libpng12-dev armhf 1.2.54-6   Unable to connect to
>   raspbian-us.ngc292.space:http: Fetched 712 kB in 26s (26.8 kB/s) E:
>   Failed to fetch
>   http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig-dev_2.1-3.1_armhf.deb
>   Could not connect to raspbian-us.ngc292.space:80 (198.211.116.210). -
>   connect (113: No route to host) E: Failed to fetch
>   http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-dev_1.2.54-6_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to raspbian-us.ngc292.space:http: E: Unable to fetch
>   some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Can you reach / ping that site? raspbian-us.ngc292.space ? Have you tried running that recommendation at the end "run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing" ? Have you tried a different mirror?

Comment: @Darius i tried using --fix-missing and it didn't work. the command itself tries different mirrors but it still fails. how else do i get the packages from other mirrors? i tried pinging the link and it says "destination host unreachable"

Comment: Do you have internet access at all from that Raspberry Pi? Almost as if you don't have internet access... I had checked the URL - the URL is valid, and the .deb package exist exactly there.. so somehow your Raspberry Pi does not have access to it. Something in your local network preventing access.